# git repo for dotfiles - clone to homefolder

Tags: linux, configuration, repository, git

I'm learning git, and the test case I'm using it for is keeping a repo of my linux profile settings (.bashrc .profile .tmux.conf etc)

on my main machine, the repo is created at the home folder: 
base=/home/bvector/
files=/home/bvector/.profile, etc

but when I go to clone the repo on machine2, it goes to /home/bvector/home (as the repo is called home)
base=/home/bvector/home/
files=/home/bvector/home/.profile, etc

Is there a way to have the cloned repo be based in my home folder with all the files in the correct place by default? Everything I've read says you cant clone a repo to a nonempty directory, which would make it a lot more cumbersome to have the repo on multiple machines and be able to seamlessly commit changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Github](http://github.com/) has just launched a set of new pages describing how to use Github for this scenario.

http://dotfiles.github.com/

Comment: this is an amazing resource, and it is so useful I'm going to select it as the answer, even though my answer solved my problem, this is probably the best way to do it

Answer (score 2):

An easy (inelegant?) thing to do would be:

```
git clone --bare whatever ~/.git
```

The `--bare` option tells it to basically checkout the contents of a normal `.git` directory (so it won't check out a working copy), and put into the directory `~/.git`.  You can use `git checkout <file>` to get individual files, or `git reset --hard` to replace all your existing files with their equivalent in your git repository, if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~
git init
git remote add origin ssh://host/repo.git
git pull origin master
```

this works for this situation. from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443927/git-clone-into-home-directory